# Evaluate $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(f(n+1)-f(n))$ where $f(n)=|B_{2n}|^{1/2n}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, bernoulli-numbers

> Let $f(n)=|B_{2n}|^{1/2n}$
>   where $B_{2n}$ is the $(2n)$-th Bernoulli's number. Evaluate the limit
>   $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(f(n+1)-f(n)).$$

How can I calculate this limit?

Comment: *Hint.* We know that $$B_{2n} = (-1)^{n+1} \cdot \frac{2(2n)!}{(2\pi)^{2n}} \zeta(2n). $$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since
$B_{2n}
=\dfrac{(-1)^{n+1}2(2n)!}{(2\pi)^{2n}}\zeta(2n)
$
and
$n!
=\approx \sqrt{2\pi}\dfrac{n^{n+1/2}}{e^n}e^{1/(12n)+O(1/n^3)}
$,

$\begin{array}\\
B_{2n}
&=\dfrac{(-1)^{n+1}2(2n)!}{(2\pi)^{2n}}\zeta(2n)\\
&=\dfrac{(-1)^{n+1}2\sqrt{4\pi n}\dfrac{(2n)^{2n}}{e^{2n}}e^{1/(24n)+O(1/n^3)}}{(2\pi)^{2n}}(1+O(2^{-2n}))\\
\text{so}\\
f(n)
&=\dfrac{(2\sqrt{4\pi n})^{1/(2n)}\dfrac{2n}{e}e^{1/(48n^2)+O(1/n^4)}}{2\pi}(1+O(2^{-2n}/n))\\
&=\dfrac{(2\sqrt{4\pi n})^{1/(2n)}ne^{1/(48n^2)+O(1/n^4)}}{\pi e}(1+O(2^{-2n}/n))\\
&=\dfrac{n}{\pi e}(2\sqrt{4\pi n})^{1/(2n)}e^{1/(48n^2)+O(1/n^4)}(1+O(2^{-2n}/n))\\
&=\dfrac{n}{\pi e}(1+\dfrac{\ln(16\pi n)}{4n}+O(\ln^2(n)/n^2))(1+1/(48n^2)+O(1/n^4))(1+O(2^{-2n}/n))\\
&=\dfrac{n}{\pi e}+\dfrac{\ln(16\pi n)}{4\pi e}+O(\ln^2(n)/n)\\
&=\dfrac{n}{\pi e}+\dfrac{\ln(n)}{4\pi e}+\dfrac{\ln(16\pi )}{4\pi e}+O(\ln^2(n)/n)\\
\text{so}\\
f(n)-f(n-1)
&=\dfrac{1}{\pi e}+\dfrac{1}{4n\pi e}+o(1)\\
\end{array}
$

Comment: Nice, I don't understand just one thing, why we have $\bigl(\zeta(2n)\bigr)^{1/(2n)}=\bigl(1+O(2^{-2n})\bigr)^{1/(2n)}=1+O(2^{-2n}/n)$. (I'm curius about the second equality.)

Comment: Ah, I see, it comes from Maclaurin expansion of $\sqrt[n]{1+x^n}$.

Answer (score 3):

Hint. An asymptotic approximation of the Bernoulli numbers can be found [HERE](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BernoulliNumber.html) (see formula (40)). It can be obtained from the [Stirling approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) $n!\sim\sqrt{2\pi n}(n/e)^n$:
$$|B_{2n}|
=\frac{2(2n)!}{(2\pi)^{2n}}\zeta(2n)\sim 2\sqrt{2\pi(2n)}\,\left(\frac {2n}{2\pi\,e}\right)^{2n}\implies f(n)=|B_{2n}|^{1/(2n)}\sim \frac n{\pi\,e}.$$
By using a more precise variant of the above approximation for the factorial, you should be able to evaluate the limit of $f(n+1)-f(n)$.

Comment: I think that we need a slightly better asymptotic formula as $f(n) = \frac{n}{\pi e}(1+o(1))$ is not enough to compute $f(n+1) - f(n)$. We can check that $$ |B_{2n}|^{1/2n} = \frac{n}{e\pi} + \frac{\log n}{4e\pi} + C + o(1) $$ for some constant $C$.

Comment: @Sangchul Lee Yes, you are correct. Thanks.

Comment: In my answer I got $C=\ln(16\pi)/(4\pi e)$.

Comment: OK. I just gave a hint since in OP's question there is no effort shown!